# How to convert new TypefaceSpan("cursive") or custom Typefacespan in html format?

Tags: android, html, font-face, spannablestring, android-typeface

I am using SpannableStringBuilder to convert the string data into spannable string and then using Html.toHtml(spannable) to make it in html format.
Now my problem is, I am not able to convert my TypefaceSpan or custom TypefaceSpan  into html format i.e something like `**<p> <font face="cursive">This is some text!</font>   </p>**`

```
spannableString = new SpannableStringBuilder(customTxtEditor.getText());

Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fonts/arial.ttf");

spannableString.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(font.toString()), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

or

```
spannableString.setSpan(font.getStyle(), startSelection, endSelection, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: have you try Html.fromHtml(htmlstring) ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana thanks for reply..  Html.fromHtml(htmlstring) is used to convert html to string.. But in my case, I want to convert  TypefaceSpan i.e  is in string format and want to convert in Html code.